# What was the answer to the box riddle?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, an-unexpected-journey

## The Riddles

When Bilbo first meets Gollum in the cave in *The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey*. He asks Gollum to lead him out of the cave, but Gollum refuses unless they play a game of riddles.

## The Box Of Gold

One of the riddles Bilbo tells Gollum is that there is a box with gold inside, but there is no lock, no key, no hinge or lid.

Gullum manages to answer the riddle correctly.

**What was the answer to the riddle?**

[image: Gollum Riddles]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to this riddle is **an egg**.

Gollum didn't fall for that one.

Comment: I don't understand how an egg can be the right answer? Can you clarify.

Comment: The gold inside an egg is the yolk. There is no key. There is no lock, hinge or lid.

Comment: well, an egg doesn't look anything like a box.

Comment: Basically what wbogacz said. Don't blame me, blame J.R.R. :)

Comment: A riddle is as much poetry as it is puzzle. Sometimes imagery is part of the question.